Computing the infinitesimal generator of $X_t = \mathrm{exp}(e^{B_t})$
I'm stuck on a computation for the infinitesimal generator of the process given by:
$$X_t = e^{B_t},$$ where $B_t = \sigma W_t + at$, for $W_t$ standard BM. My attempt goes as follows.
By Ito, we have that for $f\in C^2_b(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
f(B_t) = f(B_0) + M_t + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(B_s)ds.
$$
Where M is a martingale. We then set $g(x) = f(e^x)$ and using Ito applied to $g$:
$$
g(B_t) = f(e^{B_t}) = f(e^{B_0})+ M_t + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf''(e^{X_s})X_s^2 + X_sf'(X_s) ds.
$$
Subtracting $f(e^{B_0})$, diving by t, taking expectations (note that $M_t$ is a zero-mean mgale) and sending $t$ to zero from above should give us the generator. According to my calculations this gives me that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
L_Xf(e^x) = \frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2 f''(e^x)e^{2x} + e^xf'(e^x)(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 +a).
$$
Setting $y=e^x$:
$$
L_Xf(y) = \frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2 f''(y)y^2 + yf'(y)(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 +a).
$$
This just doesn't seem right though, especially the $yf'(y)(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)$ term. Any suggestions or am I overthinking it and the above is indeed correct? Thanks for your help.

To convince yourself that this is correct I recommend to derive the SDE that is solved by $X_t=e^{B_t}=e^{\sigma W_t+at},.$

Thanks for your reply :)
